# How to validate a form with Javascript and not reload page after submit?

Tags: javascript, forms, validation

I am working with js validation and validations are working but the form gets reload just after showing the errors. I have also tried `e.preventDefault();`  it is also not working for me.

here is my validation function:

```
$('#registration_form').submit(function(e) {

   
    var error = registrationForm(false);

    if (error == false) {
        return true;
    }

    $(document).on('keyup', '#registration_form input', function() {
        registrationForm(true);
    });

    $('#registration_form select').on('change', function() {
        registrationForm(true);
    });

    return false;
});
```

Here are my validations there are four fields in my form name, email, phone, and course but I can't figure out what's wrong with my code?

```
function registrationForm(onKeyUp) {
var name = $('#name').val();
var email = $('#email').val();
var phone = $('#phone-number').val();
var course = $('#course').val();



var error = false;
var focus = false;
$(".error").remove();


if (name.length < 1) {
    $('#name_error').text(NAME_ERROR);
    if (focus == false && onKeyUp == false) {
        $('#name').focus();
        focus = true;
    }
    error = true;
} else {
    var regEx = /^[A-Za-z ]+$/;
    var validName = regEx.test(name);
    if (!validName) {
        $('#name_error').text(INVALID_NAME_ERROR);
        if (focus == false && onKeyUp == false) {
            $('#name').focus();
            focus = true;
        }
        error = true;
    } else {
        $('#name_error').text('');
        error = false;
    }
}

if (email.length < 1) {
    $('#email_error').text(EMAIL_ERROR);
    if (focus == false && onKeyUp == false) {
        $('#email').focus();
        focus = true;
    }
    error = true;
} else {
    var regEx = /^([a-z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-z]{2,6}$/;
    var validEmail = regEx.test(email);
    if (!validEmail) {
        $('#email_error').text(VALID_EMAIL_ERROR);
        if (focus == false && onKeyUp == false) {
            $('#email').focus();
            focus = true;
        }
        error = true;
    } else {
        $('#email_error').text('');
        error = false;
    }
}

if (course == null) {
    $('#course_error').text(COURSE_ERROR);
    error = true;
    if (focus == false && onKeyUp == false) {
        $('#course').focus();
        focus = true;
    }
} else {
    $('#course_error').text('');
    error = false;
}


if (phone.length < 1) {
    $('#phone_error').text(PHONE_ERROR);
    if (focus == false && onKeyUp == false) {
        $('#phone-number').focus();
        focus = true;
    }
    error = true;
} else {
    var regEx = /^[0-9 ()-]{7,15}/;
    var validName = regEx.test(phone);
    if (!validName) {
        $('#phone_error').text(VALID_PHONE_ERROR);
        error = true;
        if (focus == false && onKeyUp == false) {
            $('#phone-number').focus();
            focus = true;
        }
    } else {
        $('#phone_error').text('');
        error = false;
    }
}

return error; }
```

Comment: I don't understand why are you registering a `onchange` eventlistener after submitting the form? It simply won't work. Move the `onchange` eventlisteners out of the `submit` event listener.

Comment: Why do you return true when there's an error?  Returning true will submit/redirect your form.

Comment: @NathanChampion here I am trying to check if validation is valid or not if not then error=true. should I replace the true value with something else?

Comment: @PraneetDixit it's a select box in my form that's why I am using `onchange` for that select box.